# How to change the statements inside onDraw from another class

Tags: android, ondraw

I created a custom view called `Draw` class which has `onDraw(Canvas)`.

`onDraw()`:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawLine(1419,283,1347,243,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(1347,243,1327,291, paint);
}
```

I want to change `onDraw()` from another class. I want to add more `drawLine()` and change the values inside it.

For short, how do you override(i dont know if this is the correct term to use) `onDraw()` in `Draw` class from another class?

Btw, I am using one view and several buttons(implemented with overrode `onDraw()`) use that view.

Comment: Your `Draw` class did this already when it was defined as `class Draw extends View`, so just do the same thing again with something like `class Draw2 extends Draw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making a custom class of Line. It should hold x_start, y_start, x_stop,y_stop.

```
public class Line {
    public float x_start, y_start, x_stop, y_stop;

    public Line(float x_start, float y_start, float x_stop, float y_stop) {
        this.x_start = x_start;
        this.y_start = y_start;
        this.x_stop = x_stop;
        this.y_stop = y_stop;
    }
}
```

Make an ArrayList of lines in your view and methods to access it from the outside world.

```
public ArrayList<Line> lines;
```

Now in the onDraw

```
for(Line : lines){
  canvas.drawLine(line.x_start, line.y_start, line.x_stop, line.y_stop, paint);
}
```

Note that you must call invalidate() for the view to be redrawn

**EDIT: adding some code for a button demo**

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             // This guy adds two lines
             someView.lines.add(new Line(1, 2, 3, 4));
             someView.lines.add(new Line(4, 5, 6, 7));
             someView.invalidate();
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             // This guy adds 3 lines
             someView.lines.add(new Line(1, 2, 3, 4));
             someView.lines.add(new Line(4, 5, 6, 7));
             someView.lines.add(new Line(8, 9, 10, 11));
             someView.invalidate();
        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             // This guy removes them all
             someView.lines.clear();
             someView.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks but I think this alternative will not satisfy what I would use it for. I have several buttons and I want to draw lines according to what a button would draw. Every button has different x's and y's and number of lines to draw.

Comment: But they are all drawing on this view?

Comment: Yes, I would be using only one view.

Comment: If you are using the same view, then my solution will work. See my edit, I have added some more code so you can understand

Comment: thanks, ill get back to this later, i got to do some implementations before this.

Comment: what is that someView? Is that the `DrawView` where you do `onDraw`? If so, how do I instantiate DrawView? Because it has context in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

here is what you can do

Inside your custom class have an arraylist say "lines"

`ArraList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();`

Now Line is class to to store Line co-ordinates.

```
Class Line {
   int x_start,y_start,x_stop,y_stop;
 }
```

Draw these line as follows inside onDraw methodof view.

 `for(Line line : lines){
  canvas.drawLine(line.x_start, line.y_start, line.x_stop, line.y_stop, paint);
}`

**now here is main part**
create method drawLines as follow

```
public void drawLines(ArrayList<Line> lines) {
    this.lines = lines;
    invaliadte();//this will call ondraw again
    // can also call postInvalidate()

}
```

Now you just need to call customView.drawLines(lines); and done..

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: how should I input the values of `x_start`,`y_start` etc from another class, say, `MainActivity`

Comment: Inside main activity create one instance of you custom object as below CutomView customView = finviewById(R.id.someid); now create Arraylist of lines as below ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>(); add values to this list lines.add(new Line(10,20,30,40)); now pass this list of lines to view call drawLines(lines); hope this helps

Comment: plus inside my code in drawLines method instead of this.lines = lines try Collections.copy(this.lines,lines)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was doing CustomView customView= new CustomView(this);. I forgot that I should be passing it to the view that I added in xml. Sorry i can only upvote your post because your answer and Bojan's are the same and he answered this question earlier. Thanks for helping anyways!

Comment: no worrys u r problem is solved thats what is important